# How can I add extra text as new part of existing image gif?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, image-processing

I have this image in the original :

[image: Gif Image]

I want to edit the gif by code and to add a text to it at the bottom and make the text as part of the gif image.

For example like this :

I marked with red the gray background and the text I want to add to the first image, this is what I mean the gray part and the text the time and date.

[image: Marked in red at the bottom to show what I mean by adding the gray background and the text.]

The text at the bottom the date and time I want to add it to the gif image the first gif image I show here only the text or also part of the gray background but something like the second image.

To add more pixels or something as the gray background at the bottom and then write on it the text the time and date and then to save the original gif with the made changes.

The second image here is just example of what I want to archive on the first image.

The text is not matter now what it will be but I want to be able to edit the gif add some text at the bottom as part of it and save the gif.

What I tried so far :

Created a new class with this code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Text;

namespace Wpf_Download_Files
{
    class DrawOnImage
    {
        public Image DrawText(String text, String subText, Image img)
        {
            var textColor = Color.Black;
            var backColor = Color.Transparent;

            var textFont = new Font("Arial", 15);
            Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

            var subTextFont = new Font("Arial", 7);
            Brush subTextBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

            //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
            img = new Bitmap(img);
            Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

            //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
            SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, textFont);
            SizeF subTextSize = drawing.MeasureString(subText, subTextFont);

            //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
            img.Dispose();
            drawing.Dispose();

            //create a new image of the right size
            img = new Bitmap(((int)textSize.Width + (int)subTextSize.Width) - ((int)textSize.Width / 3), (int)textSize.Height + 15);

            drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            drawing.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;

            //paint the background
            drawing.Clear(backColor);

            //Draw Text
            drawing.DrawString(text, textFont, textBrush, 5, 0);

            //Drawing Line
            var linePen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
            var height = (int)textSize.Height;
            var width = (int)textSize.Width;

            drawVerticalLine(drawing, linePen, 1, 0, height + 5);
            drawHorizontalLine(drawing, linePen, 0, height + 5, width / 3);

            //Darw Subtext
            drawing.DrawString(subText, subTextFont, subTextBrush, width / 3, height);

            drawing.Save();

            textBrush.Dispose();
            drawing.Dispose();

            return img;
        }

        private void drawHorizontalLine(Graphics graphics, Pen pen, int x, int y, int width)
        {
            graphics.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x + width, y);
        }

        private void drawVerticalLine(Graphics graphics, Pen pen, int x, int y, int height)
        {
            graphics.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x, y + height);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the main form I did :

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Drawing.Image img =
                System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"d:\Downloaded Images\Image0.gif");
            DrawOnImage drawonimage = new DrawOnImage();
            drawonimage.DrawText("Hello World", "utt 12345", img);
```

But it's not adding any background at the bottom and no text.

Comment: Shalom, are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: @DarkTemplar Shalom , I'm using wpf

Comment: The System.Drawing namespace is part of Winforms, not WPF. Even if you are using it in a WPF application, the question does not have much to do with WPF. I have removed the tag.

Comment: If you are using WPF may I suggest of a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Working.

Changed the code in the class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Text;

namespace Wpf_F
{
    class DrawOnImage
    {
        public void DrawText(String text, String path, Image img)
        {
            int footerHeight = 30;
            Bitmap bitmapImg = new Bitmap(img);// Original Image
            Bitmap bitmapComment = new Bitmap(img.Width, footerHeight);// Footer
            Bitmap bitmapNewImage = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height + footerHeight);//New Image
            Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapNewImage);
            graphicImage.Clear(Color.White);
            graphicImage.DrawImage(bitmapImg, new Point(0, 0));
            graphicImage.DrawImage(bitmapComment, new Point(bitmapComment.Width, 0));
            graphicImage.DrawString(text, new Font("Arial", 15), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, bitmapImg.Height + footerHeight / 6);
            bitmapNewImage.Save(path);
            bitmapImg.Dispose();
            bitmapComment.Dispose();
            bitmapNewImage.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

In the main form :

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Drawing.Image img =
                System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"d:\Downloaded Images\Image0.gif");
            DrawOnImage drawonimage = new DrawOnImage();
            drawonimage.DrawText("Hello World", @"d:\Downloaded Images\Image00001.gif", img);
```

The result is :

[image: New gif image]

The only problem is how to replace the original gif image with the changes instead creating a new gif image ?

And maybe adding a background behind the text could be nicer, not sure how to do it.

Comment: You never actually show us your saving code. Note, gif is a bit problematic since it has a limited colour palette, and you remove that palette when you perform `New Bitmap(img)`. If you would re-save that as gif, you will lose all palette optimisation of the original image, and the framework will just apply a default palette to it, probably making it look awful. Though if you keep it in 256 colour mode, `Graphics.FromImage` will simply not work at all. The actual solution, to edit in 256-colour mode, is a lot more complex.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I missed the `bitmapNewImage.Save(path);` line. You're not giving this function call an argument, so it will always save as png, and it can't overwrite the original file since the `Image.FromFile` keeps it locked as long as it's not disposed. A workaround is to read the image bytes instead and load that as Bitmap using a `MemoryStream`.